# Override animation of collapse Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm actually use Bootstrap collapse horizontally instead of Offcanvas [Bootstrap collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)! . I would like to override the default collapse animation and use this style :

```
div {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
```

Thanks in advance for you support and help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to attach it to the collapsing class. Something like:

```
.collapsing {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks joshhunt for your reply. It seems work only for vertically collapsing. I didn't found how can i override it that's why I have used bootstrap off canvas.